# How do I get the status from the Task<Void> returned by ConnectionsClient methods?

Tags: android, google-nearby

I am using the [ConnectionsClient API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/connection/ConnectionsClient), including `startAdvertising()`, which returns a `Task<Void>`. The javadoc for [`startAdvertising()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/connection/ConnectionsClient.html#startAdvertising(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection.ConnectionLifecycleCallback,%20com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection.AdvertisingOptions)) includes this statement:

> Possible result status codes include:
>
> - STATUS_OK if advertising started successfully.
> - STATUS_ALREADY_ADVERTISING if the app is already advertising.
> - STATUS_OUT_OF_ORDER_API_CALL if the app is currently connected to remote endpoints; call stopAllEndpoints() first.

How do I get these status values after calling `startAdvertising()`?

I know  that the Task API enables me to create an [`OnSuccessListener`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/OnSuccessListener.html) and [`OnFailureListener`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/OnFailureListener.html), but I want to be able to distinguish among different failure cases (specifically, `STATUS_ALREADY_ADVERTISING` is a benign failure). Because the type is `Task<Void>`, calling `getResult()` when it is passed to the `onSuccess()` method doesn't provide useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a helper method for converting a Task into a status code. This example method is blocking but it would look similar for when asynchronous. The try/catch maps directly to OnSuccessListener/OnFailureListener.

```
import static com.google.android.gms.common.api.CommonStatusCodes.ERROR;
import static com.google.android.gms.common.api.CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS;

import android.support.annotation.CheckResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

@CheckResult
public static int waitForTask(String methodName, Task<?> task) {
  try {
    Tasks.await(task);
    return SUCCESS;
  } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {    
    if (e instanceof InterruptedException) {
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }

    Exception taskException = task.getException();
    if (taskException instanceof ApiException) {
      return ((ApiException) taskException).getStatusCode();
    }

    return ERROR;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind looking at the comment I made on the other answer?

Comment: startDiscovery() and startAdvertising() (and pretty much every other method on ConnectionsClient) all return a Task. Use my answer to see if the task ran successfully.

Comment: requestConnection(), which the other answer alludes to, also returns a Task. You need to listen to it's task too, because the device that called requestConnection may fail to connect. onConnectionResult() is only invoked if you first successfully connected to the remote device.

Answer (score 2):

All status codes are in [ConnectionsStatusCodes](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/connection/ConnectionsStatusCodes) class. In [startAdvertising](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/connection/ConnectionsClient.html#startAdvertising(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection.ConnectionLifecycleCallback,%20com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection.AdvertisingOptions)) method, the third param is a [ConnectionLifecycleCallback](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/connection/ConnectionLifecycleCallback), you can use it to receives these status codes. For example:

```
final Activity activity = this;
final ConnectionLifecycleCallback callback = new ConnectionLifecycleCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionInitiated(String endpointId, ConnectionInfo connectionInfo) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionResult(String endpointId, ConnectionResolution resolution) {
        int statusCode = resolution.getStatus().getStatusCode();
        switch (statusCode) {
            case ConnectionsStatusCodes.STATUS_OK:
                break;
            case ConnectionsStatusCodes.STATUS_ALREADY_ADVERTISING:
                break;
            case ConnectionsStatusCodes.STATUS_OUT_OF_ORDER_API_CALL:
                break;  
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected(String endpointId) {

    }
};

Nearby.getConnectionsClient(activity).startAdvertising("name", "serviceId", callback, new AdvertisingOptions.Builder().build());
```

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure your answer is correct. I believe the `ConnectionLifecycleCallback` isn't called until a connection is made. I'm trying to determine whether advertising started successfully.